# Probabilities of throws of Archimedian solids

Tags: probability

For the [Platonic solids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platonic_solid) (and for e.g. the 10-sided dice), each face has trivially equal
probability of showing up on a random throw. What could one say about throwing the Archimedian
solids from math and/or physics?

Comment: Your question ('what could one say..') is quite vague. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Hard to say. With a spinner with segments of different lengths on the circumference, the likelihood of one of them is just the arc length over the circumference. With semi-regular solids, the smaller area faces are typically farther out from the center, so higher potential energy if the solid lands there. also correspondingly less stable when it has not quite settled into final position.

Comment: It seems to me that the implied question is clear. Suppose one takes a particular Archimedean solid, say the [rhombicuboctahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhombicuboctahedron) for concreteness, and throws it on the table.  One face must be uppermost when the solid comes to rest.  It is clear that all the faces in each conjugacy class are equiprobable. But what are the relative probabilities of the three (or two) conjugacy classes?

Comment: Relevant: [Probabilities of Non-Regular Dice](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/48557/25554); [Fair but irregular polyhedral dice](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/46684/fair-but-irregular-polyhedral-dice)

Answer (score 0):

The cuboctahedron and icosidodecahedron both have the same edge arrangements so they would probably be less complicated calculations. Calculating face area x the # of faces for each n-gon divided by total surface area would probably arrive at a close estimate.

All semi regular solids have the same vertex arrangements, yet the other semi regular solids have multiple edge configurations (2 or 3 types)

Nowadays, most dice are plastic and once they get much larger than an icosahedron they end up being structurally unsound as the figure becomes more likely to have deformations. So, simply rolling a die thousands of times may is not the way to go either.

Dihedral angles would probably factor in to te equation whatever it may be.....

Comment: Distance of the face from the center may also have an influence on the probability of landing on that face. Consider a polygonal prism whose end faces are relatively small and far apart--such as an unsharpened wooden pencil with hexagonal cross-section that you might buy in a store. If you toss the pencil, the probability it will land standing straight up, and not fall over, is extremely small; I think it will be much smaller than the ratio of the area of its end faces to the area of its side faces.

Comment: Of course an Archimedean solid would not have as dramatic a bias to land on a face nearer the center, but I don't think we can simply dismiss the possibility that there is _some_ effect of this sort. The links cited by MJD may help illustrate some of the difficulties.